# Unable to find action 'handleChange' on the controller of c:picklist_example Failing descriptor: {c:picklist_example}

Tags: lightning

picklist_example cmp

```
<aura:component >
    <aura:attribute name="selected" type="string" default="1"/>
    <lightning:select name="select1" label="How many tickets" value="{!v.selected}"  onchange="{!c.show}">
        <option value="">choose one..</option>
        <option value="1">one</option>
        <option value="2">two</option>
        <option value="3">three</option>
        
    </lightning:select>
    <br/><br/>
    
    <aura:attribute name="options" type="list" default="[{'label':'java','value':'ocjp'}
                                                        {'label':'sfdc','value':'admin'}
                                                        {'label':'aws','value':'aws01'}]"/>
    <aura:attribute name="value" type="list" default="option1"/>
    
           <lightning:checkboxGroup name="Checkbox Group"
                                 label="certifications"
                                 options="{!v.options}"
                                 value="{!v.value}"
                                 onchange="{!c.handleChange}"/>
    
</aura:component>
```

controller

```
({
    show : function(component, event, helper) {
        var result=event.getParam('value');
        alert(result);
        
    },
    handleChange: function (component, event) {
        alert(event.getParam('value'));
    }
})
```

Application

```
<aura:application extends="force.slds" >
    <c:picklist_example/>
</aura:application>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you give the select component an aura:id attribute value, and get the value of the component in the JS methods directly? Something like this:

Picklist_Example component:

```
<aura:component >
    <aura:attribute name="selected" type="string" default="1"/>
    <lightning:select aura:id="select1" name="select1" label="How many tickets" value="{!v.selected}"  onchange="{!c.show}">
        <option value="">choose one..</option>
        <option value="1">one</option>
        <option value="2">two</option>
        <option value="3">three</option>
        
    </lightning:select>
    <br/><br/>
    
    <aura:attribute name="options" type="list" default="[
                                                        {'label':'java','value':'ocjp'},
                                                        {'label':'sfdc','value':'admin'},
                                                        {'label':'aws','value':'aws01'}
                                                        ]"/>
    <aura:attribute name="values" type="list" default="ocjp"/>
    
           <lightning:checkboxGroup aura:id="checkboxGroup" name="checkboxGroup"
                                 label="certifications"
                                 options="{!v.options}"
                                 value="{!v.values}"
                                 onchange="{!c.handleChange}"/>
    
</aura:component>
```

Picklist_ExampleController JS method:

```
({
    show : function(component, event, helper) {
        var result=component.find("select1").get("v.value");
        console.log(result);
        alert(result);
    },
    handleChange: function (component, event) {
        var result=event.getParam("value");
        console.log(result);
        alert(result);
    }
})
```

Comment: Not working..I am facing the same issue with other components too unable to find action.is their any other possible issue apart from code?

Comment: It had worked on my side - I've edited the answer to include the full code, you might have been missing something somewhere else (I think the main one was the comma separating your options)